# actions on google not using correct voice/personality

Tags: actions-on-google

So I created this trivia game on Actions on Google for the Google Assistant, and one of the options is to choose the voice/personality that will talk when you're playing the game.  I chose the "Mr. Montgomery" voice.  [image: screenshot]  You can hear the voice for yourself here https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/trivia

I published the game, but when I try it on my Google Home, it's not using the Mr Montgomery voice, it's using the voice set in this other option I found that lets you choose the voice gender but it doesn't give an example.  I changed it to male and it is a male voice, but it isn't the Mr Montgomery voice given in the preview. [image: screenshot]  Is there something else I have to do to make it use the Mr Montgomery voice?